# Laravel-backpack show total of column

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need insert two integration to a list view:
1) a custom text
2) for 2 columns of the list the total value...
What is the best approach? May be override the list view?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you please explain in more detail? Please use Google Translate if it's easier for you.

Comment: Thank you in advance.
In a list view i need show the sum of an entire column at the bottom of the list itself; and a little custom text under the list.
I have created a screenshot at this url: http://www.andreabersi.com/a.png

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think it's better to override the list view and in you crudcontroller be sure you specify your list view.

```
$this->crud->setListView('your-list-view');
```

Comment: Thank you; i have try with a custom view; but the data in the view are populated by an ajax call...i am confused....